# making GET request from a page given same parameters as browser is not working on golang

Tags: go, debugging, web-scraping, request, web-crawler

I'm trying to make a GET request to https://ccmspa.pinellascounty.org/PublicAccess/default.aspx given the same paramaters as the browser(the headers), but it's not working only in this page; in any other page works fine.

When making request on the browser I get a 302 status [image]

But when making requests with the same headers on golang it's not working:

[image]

```
func Get() ([]*http.Cookie, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", ep, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
    req.Header.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.Set("Host", "ccmspa.pinellascounty.org")
    req.Header.Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none")
    req.Header.Set("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36")

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("err: ",err)
        return nil, err
    }
    log.Println("status: ", response.StatusCode)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    ioutil.WriteFile("./data2.html", body, 0644)
    return nil, nil
}
```

Which is weird, but weirdest is when using postman,I get 200 status instead:
[image]

Could you please help me what's the setup I need to do in order to get it done.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

It was because the client was following the redirect, so in order NOT to follow redirect:

```
client := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
    }
```